# How to make a query which gets and lists data from the last entry?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

How do you make a query which gets data and lists it from the last entry in order of the ID adding it onto the code shown below,

Example which needs add on,

```
$data_table = "posts";
$per_page = 8;
$start = $_GET['start'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *
                        FROM $data_table 
                       LIMIT $start,$per_page") or die(mysql_error());
```

Any code examples and Information would be useful, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify an ORDER BY clause:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *
                        FROM $data_table 
                    ORDER BY id DESC
                       LIMIT $start,$per_page") or die(mysql_error());
```

If there's no ORDER BY clause, there's no guarantee about data order.